# Creating a generator expression for hailstone sequence

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

### Created the below generator function:

```
def hailstone(n):
    yield n
    while n > 1:
        n = n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else n * 3 + 1
        yield n
```

Which works for me as a generator function for hailstone sequence, now I'm trying to generate the same output but from a generator expression (one-liner).

I'm trying to produce it in this direction:

```
hailstone = (num // 2 if num % 2 == 0 else num * 3 + 1 for i in range("something here"))
```

Where num is passed as the first number.
I notice that using range may not be the right path but I need a stop condition.

### Main things I'm trying to figure out:

1. How can I pass the next() output back to the genrator to produce the sequence?
2. How to provide the stop condition?

Any help performing this task?

Comment: There's not good way to turn a while-loop like this  which depends on the values inside the body as a condition to stop into a generator expression. Just use this.

Comment: To use a generator expression, you'd need to produce an infinite sequence, then use a `take_while` function or something. Generator expressions are typically used when you know ahead of time how many iterations you'll do (or at least the max number of iterations possible). Iterating until a condition is meant is a poor use-case for list comprehensions/generator expressions, since those constructs are meant to iterate over existing iterables.

Comment: Yes, comprehension constructs are designed around expressing *mapping/filtering* transformations on iterables. They aren't meant to be a catch-all to transform everything into a one-liner. Python is a sufficiently dynamic language that lets you do all sorts of hocus-pocus, so I imagine there is some way to accomplish what you want, but **you definitely** shouldn't do it that way.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think you could answer that with the example and add what you've stated here and it would be a pretty valuable answer

Comment: `hailstone = lambda num: (num if i == 0 else (num:=num // 2) if num % 2 == 0 else (num:=num * 3 + 1) for i, _ in enumerate(iter(lambda: num, 1)))` It's ugly, don't use it.

Comment: @AndrejKesely clever use of the two-argument form of iter, but boy is it gross `iter(lambda: num, 1)`. ... I think I'd prefer `takewhile` and I really dislike that function

Comment: Guys thank you for all the replies. @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah it felt like a wrong use of generators trying to make this happen but that was the assignment I got.

Answer (score 1):

## generator expression for hailstone sequence using recursion

```
def hailstone_sequence(input_num):
    return [input_num] if input_num == 1 else ([input_num] + hailstone_sequence(input_num // 2) if input_num % 2 == 0 else [input_num] + hailstone_sequence(3 * input_num + 1))


for i in hailstone_sequence(11):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments, generator expressions are not the correct tool for the job here. Generator expressions and list comprehensions are meant to produce an iterable **from an existing iterable**. They aren't a good fit here because you don't have an existing iterable to iterate over.

With the understanding that any use of a generator expression would be forced, I'd do it by iterating over an infinite iterable, then taking while a condition is met:

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

def next_hailstone(n):
    return n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else n * 3 + 1

last = 1000  # Starting number
infinite_seq = (last := next_hailstone(last) for _ in count(0))
finite_seq = takewhile(lambda n: n > 1, infinite_seq)

print(list(finite_seq))
```

Notes:

- This requires Python 3.8+ to make use of [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=`). Without assignment expressions, it's quite difficult to maintain state from one iteration to the next, which is required for this problem (another sign that this is the wrong tool for the job).
- `count(0)` is just there to provide an infinite iterable. You could replace it with anything else that can be iterated forever (like a generator function of just an infinite `while` loop containing a `yield None`).
- What I've written here is essentially a *reduction*. The built-in tools to accomplish tasks like this, if you/you teacher insists on being fancy, is [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). I'm a Functional Programmer, and I love `reduce`. In reality though, a simple loop will be more appropriate most of the time.
- Please, don't do this in real code. Again, constructs like generator expressions and list comprehensions are meant to create new iterables from existing iterables. Anything else is arguably an abuse of them.